# Removing duplicates from a different table - Criteria based

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Morning

I need to remove duplicates based on 3 fields matching. I have put together a line of code based on one criteria but need to add more.

**My code:**

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE tbl_Added.*, tbl_Added.[NUM_CUST]FROM tbl_Added WHERE (((tbl_Added.[NUM_CUST]) In (Select tbl_Removed.[NUM_CUST] from tbl_Removed)));")
```

**Extra field names I am looking to add are:**
- NeedType
- CrackID

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**
I am also trying the below VBA to no avail

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE tbl_Added.*, tbl_Added.[NUM_CUST],tbl_Added.[ID_CRAC] FROM tbl_Added WHERE (((tbl_Added.[NUM_CUST],tbl_Added.[ID_CRAC]) In (Select tbl_Removed.[NUM_CUST], tbl_Removed.[ID_CRAC] from tbl_Removed)));")
```

Comment: Access has a query assistant to find duplicates, use it. -- Be careful with the deletion: usually you want to keep one instance of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want this to be run through VBA

Comment: Use the query assistant to find duplicates, and then check the SQL code and use that code on VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL will return the `NUM_CUST` field for records which are duplicated based on equality of the three fields you mention:

```
SELECT NUM_CUST 
FROM tbl_added 
GROUP BY NUM_CUST, NEEDTYPE, CRACKID 
HAVING Count(NUM_CUST) > 1
```

From here you will need to decide whether you would like to delete all such records from your table, or delete only the duplicate records, retaining a single instance of each.